# Storage from a terminated EC2 instance not getting automatically added to any existing instances

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-ebs

I had three EC2 instances of a total of 30GiB and ran out of space on the instance running *Cloud9*, so I terminated one to reclaim storage, however even after 10 hours, the storage from the terminated instance has not been added to either of the other two instances.

Shouldn't the storage reclaimed from the terminated instance be automatically added to either of the active instance?

The terminated is confirmed terminated, does not display on the EC2 instances' dashboard.

Answer (score 0):

I explored the AWS Docs and realized:

1. The storage isn't added (aka *attached*) automatically!
2. If you have terminated your EC2 instance, like I had, then you need to create a new EC2 instance, then *detach* the storage from this newly created instance and *attach* it to your existing instance and then `mount` this to an existing `mount point` or to a new one.

**Deep appreciation for the thorough, detailed and abundant official documentation of AWS.**

Comment: it's not really like this. When you create an instance you have the option to terminate the ebs(storage) upon terminating the ec2. So when you terminate ec2, all the 'storage' attached to the instance is deleted as well(seems like you had this case). You do not need to create a new instance just to get new ebs of 10gb and then detach from that instance and attach to your old instance. You can just create a new volume and attach it to the instance without creating new instance at all.

Comment: Thanks @Riz . I agree. While the process I followed did show up in `df` but Cloud9 IDE was not recognizing the mount point, to resolve I had to run `resize2fs`.